# Spring freemarker bind - what is controller?

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

looking at the [documentation for the spring macros for freemarker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/view.html#view-velocity-forms) they talk about the 'command' object... i am confused as to what that is? at first i thought it is just the ModleMap set by the controller, but its obviously not.  What is the "bind" actually used for?

Answer (score 0):

The command object it's referring to is the form-backing object used by Spring MVC. If you want to use full form handling, I strongly suggest you go and read up on the rest of the Spring MVC documentation before tackling it.

However, you can safely ignore the form-handling stuff if you so choose, and just access the `ModelMap` directly from your freemarker templates.

Comment: I have read through the documentation, but there doesnt seem to be much on the types of questions I ask here... Do you have a link to docs that explains this type of stuff?